# Angular 2 - displaying a component above routeroutlet

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a very simple Angular 2 app that is not showing a component where I'd expect it to be. Am I able to display a component outside of the router-outlet component?

My app.component.html looks like this...

```
<login></login>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

However the login component is never displayed.
It is displayed if I put it inside one of the components displayed in the router-outlet.

Should Angular 2 be able to do this or should I change my design?

My app.component.ts looks like this...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';   
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TilesService } from '../app/shared/services/tiles.service'
import { LocationService } from '../app/shared/services/location.service'

import {LoginComponent} from '../app/shared/login/login.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'tc-app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.scss').toString(), 
            require('../../public/scss/styles.scss').toString()
    ],

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
                TilesService,
                LocationService,
                LoginComponent
               ]
})

export class AppComponent {  pageTitle: string = 'TileCase'; }
```

Comment: You question doesn't show a lot about your design. This works of course.

Comment: I have added the app.component.ts code. What else would you like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `LoginComponent` into the directives-array:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tc-app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./app.component.scss').toString(),
        require('../../public/scss/styles.scss').toString()
    ],

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LoginComponent],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        TilesService,
        LocationService
    ]
})
```

Comment: Ahh yes that's it, I'd added it to the providers by mistake. Thanks.